# Html Data-Icon messing with input margins

Tags: html, input, margin

I'm trying to insert a data-icon to two input fields, but they keep shifting my input fields to the right, like they where adding a margin-left to it.

I'm using z-index:2 to the icons in order to keep them floating above the fields and they do, but the added margin is still there.

Here's my css:

```
#loginBox input#username, #loginBox input#password {
    height: 20px;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 32px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(178, 178, 178);
    box-sizing : content-box;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.6) inset;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
#loginBox [data-icon]:before {
    content: attr(data-icon);
    font-family: FontomasCustomRegular;
    color: #999;
    position: relative;
    left: 25px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

And here's a screenshot:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that it's a margin? Did you check firebug?

Comment: No, not sure. I just said it seems like a margin.
Adding margin:0; do te css does nothing also.

Comment: What browser and does it happen only after adding the icon?

Comment: On IE it could be due to padding: 5px 5px 5px 32px; as IE tends to add padding outside the text box.

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem, since even without any margin or padding applied, the icons still had a little space on the left.

I did a workaround by creating small png icons, instead of using Data-Icon.

Comment: Any way you can put it on jsfiddle or post full code?

Answer (score -2):

Sanjeev and Stéphanie Walter's code in nearly identical

http://www.infotuts.com/email-verification-php/

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/27/login-and-registration-form-with-html5-and-css3/

```
[data-icon]:after {
    content: attr(data-icon);
    font-family: 'FontomasCustomRegular';
    color: rgb(106, 159, 171);
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 35px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

**position: absolute;**